# Simple jQuery plugin not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Good Day,

I am writing my first jQuery plugin.  I grabbed the code from the learn jquery website.  Here is the HTML with Javascript:

```
<div>Hello World</div>
<br>
<br>
<div>Hola Mundo</div>

<a href="http://www.nbcnews.com">My Link</a>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.greenify.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {
    $('div').greenify({
        text: "Hola",
        color: "#FF0000"
    });
});
```

And here is jquery.greenify.js:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            text: "Somewhere in time",
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white"
        }, options );

        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).text(settings.text);

            if (settings.color) {
                $(this).css('color', settings.color);
            }

            if (setting.backgroundColor) {
                $(this).css('background-color', settings.backgroundColor);
            }
        });
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

For whatever reason, I don't see the changes taking effect.  I have checked the console and there were no errors.  I tried to set breakpoints with the return this.each in jquery.greenify.js to see if the code was being executed and it's not.  I downloaded a similar example from Github https://github.com/taupecat/jquery-plugin that *does* work.  I've tried to model my code after that and I'm still not having any luck.

I'm hoping another set of eye will catch something I'm clearly missing.

I've checked a couple of other question on this site, but those answers didn't pertain to my issue.

TIA,

coson

Comment: Typo: `setting.backgroundColor` should be `settings.backgroundColor`. I got an error in my JS console.

Comment: After fixing that, it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5rcrv4wt/1/

Comment: @Barmar,  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the javascript, add a closing

```
</script>
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks, but at the same time, I'm totally embarrassed.  I'll give you the points as soon as I'm able to.

Comment: No need to be embarrassed. These things happen all the time :D